# How to source a file inside a symlinked script from the folder with the actual script file?

Tags: shell, zsh

I have my dotfiles currently organized as a homeshick castle.
Located at `~/.homeshick/repos/dotfiles`

```
dotfiles
└── home
    ├── .zshrc
```

When I run `homeshick link`, homeshick symlinks the `.zshrc` into my home folder. Right now, I'm maintaining `.zshrc` as a single file containing most of my shell preferences. I wanted to break it out into a structure like

```
dotfiles
    ├── home
    ├    ├── .zshrc
    ├── shell
         ├── aliases.sh
```

(Keeping the shell folder outside the home folder prevents it from being symlinked to `~` and keeps the home folder neat and tidy)

Now the `.zshrc` file includes a line to source the aliases - 
`source '../shell/aliases.sh`. But sourcing the `.zshrc` file gives a `no such file or directory error`.

I checked and it seems that while the source command will follow a symlink, the `pwd` remains the one where the source command was called and thus prevents this structure from working.

I want to avoid using the absolute filepath (`.homesick/repos/dotfiles/shell/X.sh`) for every such source I might make from the shell folder. Any way to avoid this?

*Broken down this question is specifically about how to source files relative to the actual script file location for a symlinked script without having to resort to absolute file paths and thus not an exact duplicate of the question that was tagged by* @tripleee

Comment: link aliases to your home dir too? Don't create the link, but create .zshrc in your home dir with `suorce .homesick/repos/dotfiles/home/.zshrc` ?

Comment: Could you clarify that? Do you mean create a .zshrc in my `~` folder and put `source .homesick/repos/dotfiles/home/.zshrc` inside it? 

This would work, but then the file in my `~` folder would have just this one line and I'd have to navigate to the dotfiles repo everytime I needed to change it or even just to open it. Still hoping for a way to do it without that.

Comment: Yes I meant that. Och I know. Try something with `$0` variable. Try like `source "$(dirname "$(readlink -f "$0")")"/../shell/aliases.sh` or like `source "$(dirname "$0")"/../shell/aliases.sh`. Or try `"$BASH_SOURCE" variable instead of $0 or similar.

Comment: @KamilCuk - Thank you! This worked well for me -


   ` # Define .zshrc running directory`
    `ZSHDIR="$(dirname "$(readlink "${0}")")"`

    `# Source Aliases`
    `source "${ZSHDIR}/../shell/aliases.sh"`

Comment: Change the `${0}` to `${(%):-%N}` for it to work on shell startup as well. Since `${0}` returns the shell instead.